# print contents of a directory structure (filesystem) to CSV on the command line

Tags: command-line, filesystem, text, ls, csv

How can I catalog the contents of a filesystem to a CSV file? This is particularly useful for removable media.

I've found a couple links that point in this direction:

- [AskUbuntu.com: listing files in a directory without listing
  subdirectories and their contents in that directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289321/)
- [Hints.MacWorld.com: Create a directory list in CSV format](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060829114722873)

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This creates a CSV file `listing.csv` with file name, time stamp and size for all files in `/some/folder/` and its subfolders:

```
find /some/folder -printf '"%P";"%Tc";"%s";\n' > listing.csv
```

See the documentation for `-printf` in the [manpage for find](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/find.1.html) if you want to use other fields.

Note that it doesn't work for file names containing `"` characters.

Comment: Florian, I'm getting a `>` prompt when I run this command and I have to `Ctrl+c` to get out of it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you need this to access the files on your external harddrive a better solution would be to create an index with extra options on `updatedb`

add this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias updatedb-external='sudo updatedb -l 0 -o ~/.externalharddisk.db -U /media/path/to/harddrive/'
alias locate-external='locate -d ~/.externalharddisk.db:'
```

then you can query that list with that alias:

```
locate-external some-file
```

update your list with

```
updatedb-external
```