# Force nautilus to ignore extensions

Tags: command-line, nautilus, nautilus-extensions

We all know(or will know one day) that Ubuntu(or GNU/Linux in general) does not work with extensions of file to recognize what kind of file it is.Rather it uses **Magic Numbers**.

> A **Magic Number** is a number associate with every Linux file and is generally the first few bytes of the file, which identifies the file type. It is used by the Linux command line utility *file* which displays the information related to a file.

So when we check a file type with the `file` command, it gives appropriate file type regardless of it's extensions.

So a mp3 file gives

```
aditya@aditya-desktop:~/Music$ file 'music.mp3'
music.mp3: Audio file with ID3 version 2.3.0, contains: MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1,  64 kbps, 44.1 kHz, JntStereo
aditya@aditya-desktop:~/Music$ file 'music'
music: Audio file with ID3 version 2.3.0, contains: MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1,  64 kbps, 44.1 kHz, JntStereo
aditya@aditya-desktop:~/Music$ file 'music.txt'
music.txt: Audio file with ID3 version 2.3.0, contains: MPEG ADTS, layer III, v1,  64 kbps, 44.1 kHz, JntStereo
aditya@aditya-desktop:~/Music$
```

The same expt , when tried with **Nautilus**, it considers the file a music file when it has *.mp3* or *no extension*, but when it is given *.txt* extension, it considers it a text file.

So the main question,

1. Does nautilus use extensions to recognize file?
2. How can I force nautilus to ignore extensions and use magic numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As you have noted, yes, Nautilus use file extension (when present) as a priority to determine the file type.
2. You can edit the file `/usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml`, search for the extension you want to ignore and delete the line. Below is an example.

Supose I don't want Nautilus to associate ".txt" extension and I want it to look at the "magic number" instead.

I. Edit the file:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml
```

I will look for a line with `<glob pattern="*.txt"/>` and delete it:
[image]

II. Save.

III. Run:

```
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

Done!

== Effect ==

This is how an mp3 file looks like:

[image]

This is how it looks if I change the extension to txt:

[image]

This is how it looks if I edit the file above and then change the extension:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is that some files like "txt" are quite hard to work out from magic, so will always need a glob.

Whereas something like mp3 has a defined magic sequence.