# How can I make ls only display files?

Tags: ls

I figure there has to be a way of making ls only display non-directories, but the man page doesn't make it obvious

Comment: Not sure about `ls`, but you can easily do it with the `file` command: `file /directory/containing/the/files -maxdepth 1 -not -type d`.

Comment: Another way would be to filter the output of `ls` through `grep`, something like `ls -1F /directory/containing/the/files |  grep -vE /$`. But be aware that [parsing the output of ls can be tricky](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/289321/listing-files-in-a-directory-without-listing-subdirectories-and-their-contents-i

Answer (score 138, accepted):

```
ls -p | grep -v /
```

Using `ls -p` tells `ls` to append a slash to entries which are a directory, and using `grep -v /` tells `grep` to return only lines *not* containing a slash.

Comment: I checked this one because it's my favorite answer (while i did upvote all of them), but now trying to find a way to put it in columns and reverse the order of output...

Comment: "You can use 1 switch for single column list" sorry, i did try to figure out what you meant by that, i would appreciate and example/explanation if you would, i only know what a switch is in regards to C programming

Comment: @sdkks You don't need the `1` switch when piping the output as it will default to single column in that situation. If that is what you were meaning.

Comment: @thinksinbinary not sure how to make it multi column but you could search for or ask your own separate question and someone will know.

Comment: this is not a good solution, it does cut out files containing / in its path: `mkdir a;touch a/b; ls a/*| grep -v /
` – a much better solution for your problem is to use `find`

Comment: You cannot have forward slashes in filenames in Linux.  ext3/4 doesn't allow it.  Some other underlying filesystems may theoretically support it but it wouldn't work properly in Linux; the system calls wouldn't support it and most software would be expected to have problems with it.  Don't try putting forward slashes in filenames in Linux - unless they are encoded in some way in which case it won't be an issue here.

Comment: How would you include hidden files with this?

Comment: @rgin adding a `-a` flag to the ls command should do that.

Comment: ```grep -v /$``` would filter out eny lines ending with a slash.  Fixes rubo77's corner case.

Comment: @VXDguy I don't understand the issue you or rubo77 mentioned.  As far as I understand the question we *do* want to filter out lines containing a slash because we want to filter out directories.  File names contain no slash.

Comment: @VXDguy upon re-reading, it looks like you're wanting something that works if you're running ls *of another directory*.  In which case yes your workaround would solve that.

Comment: `-p` will not add the `/` suffix for symbolic links that point to directories. Keep that in mind.

Comment: `-v` is `--invert-match`

Comment: Indeed, it's not "verbose" as in many other commands

Answer (score 36):

You may try this:

`find . -maxdepth 1 -not -type d`

And map this to a special alias.

But if you're really keen on using the `ls` command, here:

`ls -p | egrep -v /$`

Comment: `find . -maxdepth 1 -not -type d | xargs ls` - literally make ls show only the non-directory files.

Answer (score 12):

Alternatively:

```
ls -lAh | grep -v '^d'
```

This method lists in

- `-l`  Long list format
- `-A`  Displays almost all (show hidden files but don't show `.` and `..`)
- `-h`  Human readable file sizes

while grep

- `-v` Don't show matching records
- `Regular expression` filter `^d` - Those start with letter d (for directory) i.e `drwxrwxr-x <some file details> <foldername>`

If you don't want to type every time, you may make it into [an alias for your bash/shell profile.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias)

Answer (score 4):

```
ls -F | grep -v /
```

Above command displays files, But it includes symlinks, pipes, etc. If you want to eliminate them too, you can use one of the flags mentioned below.

`ls -F` appends symbols to filenames. These symbols show useful information about files.

- `@` means [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) (or that the file [has extended attributes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10/what-does-the-mean-in-ls-l)).
- `*` means [executable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions).
- `=` means [socket](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html).
- `|` means [named pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe).
- `>` means [door](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doors_(computing)).
- `/` means [directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_directory).

```
ls -F | grep -Ev '/|@|*|=|>|\|'
```

Above command displays only files.

Comment: Executables are also files. If you want loop files incl. executables, but no links, since they could be folders as well, use `for file in $(ls -1F "$path" | grep -Ev "\||/|@|=|>"); do` and access the full path using `$path/${file//\*}`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want only files and don't want to perform any operation on them, then run:

```
ls -lA | grep -v '^d'
```

Or, if you want to iterate on each file, then for me this works:

```
ls *.?*
```

Comment: Using long listing with `-l` switch will be slow if you have many files.

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to see only files, directories or both.

Or if you want to see hidden files, directories or not.

Use these bash functions:

```bash
showVisibleFilesOnly() {
  ls -p | grep -v /
}
showVisibleFoldersOnly() {
  ls -p | grep / | grep "^."
}

showOnlyFilesIncludingHidden() {
  ls -Ap | grep -v / | grep "^."
}
showOnlyFoldersIncludingHidden() {
  ls -Ap | grep / | grep "^."
}

showHiddenFoldersOnly() {
  ls -Ap | grep / | grep "^\." | grep "\."
}
showHiddenFilesOnly() {
  ls -Ap | grep -v / | grep "^\." | grep "\."
}

showAllFilesAndFoldersIncludingHidden() {
  ls -Ap
}

showHiddenFilesAndFoldersOnly() {
  ls -Ap | grep "^\."
}
```

Comment: Now you can have exactly what you want when you want it with ease

Answer (score 1):

I saw in your( @thinksinbinary ) comment on the answer by @thomasrutter , that you wanted to be able to print them in reverse order and in columns. You probably have already figured it out or moved on, but here it is:

```
ls -pr | grep -v / | column
```

- **-p** adds the forward slash ('/')  to the directory names
- **-r** reverses the order of output
- **-v** lets grep do an inverse search to print everything except the directories (*everything that doesn't have the '/' that -p put there*)
- "**column** puts it in columns" - *Captain Obvious*

Comment: i do think it's cool that on the ubuntu forum people still comment on and read your posts after a long time. I've been wanting to get back into linux in order to learn assembly and operating systems since doing so on windows is much more difficult. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `du` instead of `ls`. It will only output files. Then just `awk '{print $2}'` to output only the file path.

You have to use the -d option with du to limit depth. http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/du1.html

Comment: However, this would show the files even in subdirectories of subdirectories.

Comment: That is true. You can add the -d flag to limit the depth though. I have added an edit to my response to reflect that.

Comment: Yeah. But that would still show directories, for example, `Desktop` when run from `$HOME` and won't be an answer to this question since the questioner wants to list files only.